# Express route slash as URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is it possible to do something like this in express?

```
app.get('/.test/abc', function(req, res) {
    res.send( 'abc test' )
})
```

Meaning if i hit `localhost:3000/.test/abc` it should get `abc test`. I tested it it's not working. Do i have to encode the slash to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is correct. It does work. If it is not working then it is a problem of another part of your code.

Here is a simple example:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req);
    res.send('Hello World!')
})
app.get('/.test/abc', function(req, res) {
    res.send(
        'abc test'
    )
})
app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log('Started')
})
```

It returns `abc test` when I hit `http://127.0.0.1:3000/.test/abc`.

Comment: right but I this won't work `app.get('/.test/abc', function(req, res) {})` says the folder name is really `.test`, worked in localhost, but not in nginx server.

Comment: what do mean works in localhost and not in nginx server? are you using reverse proxy. if you are please give detailed description in the question.

Comment: my bad, wrong config in my nginx config, your answer is correct.